# Flutter TabBar unwanted space on first label

Tags: flutter, tabs, padding

`The space before the first label 'Mon' is there even when padding margins are zero.
Tried setting paddings to zero but there is still some spaces on the left on the first label.

[image]

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: MyHomePage(),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      final List<String> daysOfWeek = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];

      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Days of the Week'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero, 
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: daysOfWeek.length,
          initialIndex: 0,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(height: 50),
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                child: TabBar(
                  isScrollable: true,
                  indicatorColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                  tabs: daysOfWeek.map((String day) {
                    return Tab(
                      child: Text(
                        day,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          letterSpacing: 0.5,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: daysOfWeek.map((String day) {
                    return DayPage(day: day);
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class DayPage extends StatelessWidget {
      final String day;

      const DayPage({required this.day});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            'Content for $day',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the [breaking changes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes#released-in-flutter-316) from the [Flutter 3.16 update](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/release-notes/release-notes-3.16.0).
To fix it, follow the [migration guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/tab-alignment) to specify your desired alignment in `tabAlignment`:

```dart
TabBar(
  tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
  // ...
)
```